# Why do I have to declare a variable as mutable in order for internal functions to modify its own contents?

Tags: rust

I have a `CPU` struct with a `load_rom` method:

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{self, Read};

pub struct CPU {
    pub mem: [u8; 4096],
    V: [u8; 16],
    I: u16,
    stack: [u16; 16],
    opcode: u16,
}

impl CPU {
    pub fn new() -> CPU {
        CPU {
            mem: [0; 4096],
            V: [0; 16],
            I: 0,
            stack: [0; 16],
            opcode: 0,
        }
    }
    pub fn load_rom(&self, filepath: &str) {
        let mut rom: Vec<u8> = Vec::new();
        let mut file = File::open(filepath).unwrap();
        file.read_to_end(&mut rom);

        for (i, mut byte) in rom.iter().enumerate() {
            self.mem[i] = *byte;
        }
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

This generates the error:

```
error: cannot assign to immutable indexed content `self.mem[..]`
  --> src/main.rs:28:13
   |
28 |             self.mem[i] = *byte;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

When I create a CPU with `let mut cpu = CPU::new();` and pass `&mut self` to the `load_rom` method, everything works just fine.

If I don't use `mut` on creation, I get the error:

```
error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `cpu` as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:10:2
   |
9  |    let cpu = CPU::new();
   |        --- use `mut cpu` here to make mutable
10 |    cpu.load_rom("/Users/.../Code/Rust/chip8/src/roms/connect4.ch8");
   |    ^^^ cannot borrow mutably
```

It doesn't seem right that I have to make `cpu` mutable in order for internal functions to modify its own contents. Do I really have to declare `cpu` as mutable? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm asking a question because I don't know the answer. Thanks anyways @ildjarn.

Comment: In `load_rom` you are altering `self.mem`. Why do you think that this would be possible without `cpu` being mutable? Perhaps you could move the mutation into a factory function that returns a fully initialised `CPU` that can be bound to an immutable variable.

Comment: It's not really that I don't think cpu should be mutable, It's just that it seems weird to me that I have to declare it as mutable externally in order for internal functions to modify it's own contents. Again, new to Rust, so bear with me.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> make `cpu` mutable in order for **internal functions to modify its own contents**

(emphasis mine)

Rust is a **systems language**, which means that it attempts to give you the ability to create *fast* and *efficient* code. One of the primary ways that this is done is by providing references to existing data instead of copying it.

Rust is also a **safe language**, which (among other things) means that accessing an invalid reference should be impossible.

To accomplish both of these goals, there have to be tradeoffs. Some languages move the safety checks to runtime, enforce mandatory synchronization primitives (e.g. a mutex and friends), or some other interesting solution. Some languages avoid the mess entirely and opt to disallow references or not attempt to guarantee safety.

Rust differs from these by checking as many things at compile time as feasible. This implies that the compiler *has* to be able to reason about when and where a piece of memory might be mutated.

If it didn't know this, then you might get a reference to something within a value and then call a mutating method on that value that invalidates the reference. When you go to use the now-invalid reference... **BOOOOOM**. Your program crashes at *best*, or leaks information or creates a backdoor at *worst*.

`&mut self` is in indication to the compiler that this method might mutate the values within. It is only valid to get a mutable reference to a value that is already mutable, which is denoted by the `mut` keyword on a variable binding (`mut cpu` here).

However, this isn't *just* useful to the compiler. Knowing that something is being changed is *highly* valuable to the programmer too. Mutability in a large system adds hard-to-reason-about complexity, and being forced to explicitly list when something is and isn't mutable can be very informative and mentally freeing.

It's also useful to know the [rules for borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules) that Rust applies. These restrict you to one or the other of:

```
* one or more references (`&T`) to a resource,
* exactly one mutable reference (`&mut T`).
```

Succinctly, this can be summed as "aliasing XOR mutability".

---

If your mutation is truly internal, then you can also make use of [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/mutability.html#interior-vs-exterior-mutability), such as by using a [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) or a [`Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html). What you use depends on your needs and what kind of data you want to store.

These constructs are a good mental fit for structures like caches, where you want to "hide" the mutability from the outside. However, there are also limitations to these as the lifetime of references to the data within *must* be shortened to continue providing the "aliasing XOR mutabilty" guarantee to keep the code safe.

---

For your specific problem, I agree with the commenters that it makes sense for `load_rom` to accept a `&mut self`. It can even be simplified:

```
pub fn load_rom(&mut self, filepath: &str) {
    let mut file = File::open(filepath).unwrap();
    file.read_exact(&mut self.mem);
}
```

You may want to zero out any old data before loading. Otherwise, if you load a second ROM that's smaller than the first, data from the first ROM can leak to the second ([an actual bug from older computers / operating systems](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2456/why-would-older-video-games-include-fragments-of-source-code)).

Comment: Awesome response. So I can have one mutable reference and as many immutable ones as I want. When does this change AKA when can I use another mutable reference? When the last goes out of scope / dies?

Comment: @PatrickAllen yep, when it goes out of scope is the right way to think about it. There are *some* nuances to that you might hit eventually, but I'd let those lie until you hit them ^_^.

Comment: Ha ha, I will do. Thanks for the great response. It's reassuring to know that there are still some around here that are willing to cater to the new crowd.

Comment: @PatrickAllen FWIW, I don't disagree with the handful of comments you got on your question. I can't speak for the others, but I had no idea what you were trying to ask until your last reply, which is why I edited it into the question. I think you'll find I'm one of the harshest [tag:rust] participants and I down/close vote all sorts of poor questions and close dupes like it's going out of style. Those commenters helped extract your core question before I got here with my heavy voting hand ;-) We will *always* answer a **good and unique** question, regardless of origin.

Comment: Yeah, I get it. I tried my hardest to explain my question. I agree, but I don't agree with the sass a lot of people put into responses, especially when I tried to make it clear that I'm new to this. Either way, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Rust uses a transitive immutability model. This means that if a variable is marked as `immutable`, the variable may not be mutated, and data accessed through the variable may not be mutated.

Furthermore, if you have a mutable reference to a variable, the type system disallows any immutable references from coexisting; and so data not marked as `mut' is truly unchanging throughout the lifetime of the the immutable reference.

Together this makes it so that by default, it is not possible for there to be two mutable references to the same data at the same time. This is a requirement for efficient memory safety and thread safety; and also makes it simpler to reason about mutation in Rust code.

If you want "interior" mutability you can use `Cell<T>` or `RefCell<T>` from the `std::cell` module. However, this is probably the wrong thing to do for a CPU struct that is meant to represent a CPU that is expected to be run, and have its state change after each operation. Interior mutability should generally be reserved for performing mutation within the implementation of an operation that does not perform any logical (externally visible) mutation of an object. A CPU running operations or loading memory would not be a good candidate for this, as each operation such as "load memory", "run instruction" or whatever will alter the logical state of the CPU.

See [the `std::cell` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/) for further discussion of when you might want interior mutability.